How to close a cmd window which created by a VBS script from the script itself?
I'm generating a VBS script to remote contol outlet of APC PDU, and I will need the VBS script included in a batch file for a loop test, below is the VBS script.
apc_off.vbs
Option Explicit
'On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 500

'Telnet to PDU IP'
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 172.16.11.169"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

'Send Username
WshShell.SendKeys "apc"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

'Send Password
WshShell.SendKeys "apc"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

'Turn off Outlet
WshShell.SendKeys "olOff 3"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

'Exit APC console
WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500

And below is an example of batch file.
test.bat
for /l %%i in (1 1 1000) do (
    <code ignored>
    apc_off.vbs
    <code ignored>
    apc_on.vbs
    <code ignored>
)

When the batch script execute the apc_off.vbs, the VBS script open a cmd.exe to telnet to the APC PDU for remote on/off the outlet, but after executing it, the cmd window still is there and when next time the batch script to execute another round of VBS script and it would still open another new cmd window, so if my batch script run with 1000 cycles then it will have 1000 cmd windows be opened.

I've web searched, and found a way to terminate the cmd window thru VBS, but it also kills the primary batch window and cause termination of batch script.
test.bat
for /l %%i in (1 1 1000) do (
    <code ignored>
    apc_off.vbs
    close.vbs
    <code ignored>
    apc_on.vbs
    close.vbs
    <code ignored>
)

close.vbs
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oWmg = GetObject("winmgmts:")
strWndprs = "select * from Win32_Process where name='cmd.exe'"
Set objQResult = oWmg.Execquery(strWndprs)
For Each objProcess In objQResult
intReturn = objProcess.Terminate(1)
Next

I need help to advise how to terminate the cmd window which created by VBS itself, thanks!!!

Update: After web searching" there is a template batch script to run VBS with telnet, so I just based on the template to modify and confirm it works good for me.
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

echo/ && cls && color 9F && %__APPDIR__%mode.com 77,30 && set "_temp_vbs=%tmp%\_tmp_file_vbs_.vbs" && >"!_temp_vbs!"^
  (    
   echo= On Error Resume Next
   echo= Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
   echo= Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500 'adjust this timeout for your needs
   echo= ObjShell.AppActivate "MS Telnet CMD" 
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "o 172.16.11.169~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "apc~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "apc~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "olOff 3~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "exit~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "~"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "^]"
   echo= Wsh.sleep 500
   echo= WshShell.SendKeys "quit~"
  ) && pushd %windir%\system32\ & title <nul && title MS Telnet CMD

start "" /b "%__APPDIR__%cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" && call telnet.exe 

:loop
tasklist.exe /nh | findstr.exe /i cscript.exe >nul && goto :loop
2>nul >nul del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & popd & endlocal & exit

Then I can create another batch script for it and call by main batch script and it can automatically terminated.
For example, copy and paste it to apc_off.bat, and I can use it from below main batch.
start /wait apc_off.bat


Tried the topic you mentioned before posting this topic but failed, it could not work on my case.

But you didn't bother to mention you had tried it, so how are we supposed to know? It's also difficult to know what "my case" is as you don't provide a lot of detail. Do you call the VBS files directly in the batch without wrapping them in a cscript command? That may be part of the reason it doesn't work.

Also, if you have tried the suggestion in the duplicate you would know you need to use cmd /C in the apc_off.vbs file if you want the command window to close after execution.
